# updating state without setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form and after I submit that form I want to clear the fields. So first of all I make a copy of state that has the form data to change them immutably, then set the values to nothing. But before using setState() the state is updated, and after sending data the fields clear. That's what I want, but the question is why is the state updated before I use setState() even though I'm working with a copy of the state and not setting it yet?

```
class ContactData extends Component {
  state = {
    orderForm: {
      name: {
        elementType: 'input',
        elementConfig: {
          type: 'text',
          placeholder: 'Your Name',
        },
        value: '',
      },
      street: {
        elementType: 'input',
        elementConfig: {
          type: 'text',
          placeholder: 'Your Street',
        },
        value: '',
      },
      zipcode: {
        elementType: 'input',
        elementConfig: {
          type: 'text',
          placeholder: 'ZIP Code',
        },
        value: '',
      },

      country: {
        elementType: 'input',
        elementConfig: {
          type: 'text',
          placeholder: 'Your Country',
        },
        value: '',
      },
      email: {
        elementType: 'input',
        elementConfig: {
          type: 'email',
          placeholder: 'Your Email',
        },
        value: '',
      },

      deliveryMethod: {
        elementType: 'select',
        elementConfig: {
          options: [
            { value: 'fastest', displayValue: 'Fastest' },
            { value: 'cheapest', displayValue: 'Cheapest' },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    loading: false,
  };
  orderBtnHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const formData = {};
    for (let formElementId in this.state.orderForm) {
      formData[formElementId] = this.state.orderForm[formElementId].value;
    }
    const order = {
      ingredient: this.props.ingredient,
      price: this.props.price,
      formData: formData,
    };
    axios
      .post('/order.json', order)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(this.state.orderForm);
        const updatedOrderForm = { ...this.state.orderForm };
        const updatedFormEl = {};
        for (let keys in updatedOrderForm) {
          updatedFormEl[keys] = updatedOrderForm[keys];
        }

         for (let keys in updatedFormEl) {
           updatedFormEl[keys].value = '';
         }
        console.log(this.state.orderForm);


        this.setState({ loading: false, orderForm: updatedOrderForm });
        console.log(this.state.orderForm);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      });
  };

  inputChangeHandler = (e, id) => {
    const updatedOrderForm = { ...this.state.orderForm };
    const updatedFormEl = { ...updatedOrderForm[id] };
    updatedFormEl.value = e.target.value;
    updatedOrderForm[id] = updatedFormEl;
    this.setState({ orderForm: updatedOrderForm });
  };

  render() {
    const formArray = [];
    for (let key in this.state.orderForm) {
      formArray.push({
        id: key,
        config: this.state.orderForm[key],
      });
    }
    // console.log(formArray);
    let form = (
      <div className={classes.ContactData}>
        {formArray.map((formEl) => {
          // console.log(formEl);

          return (
            <Input
              key={formEl.id}
              label={formEl.id.toUpperCase()}
              elementConfig={formEl.config.elementConfig}
              elementType={formEl.config.elementType}
              value={formEl.config.value}
              changed={(e) => this.inputChangeHandler(e, formEl.id)}
              // options={
              //   formEl.id === 'deliveryMethod'
              //     ? formEl.config.elementConfig.options
              //     : null
              // }
            />
          );
        })}
        <Button type='Success'>ORDER</Button>
      </div>
    );
    if (this.state.loading) {
      form = <Spinner />;
    }
    return <form onSubmit={this.orderBtnHandler}>{form}</form>;
  }
}
```

I do three console.logs in this block of code:

```
 axios
      .post('/order.json', order)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(this.state.orderForm);
        const updatedOrderForm = { ...this.state.orderForm };
        const updatedFormEl = {};
        for (let keys in updatedOrderForm) {
          updatedFormEl[keys] = updatedOrderForm[keys];
        }

         for (let keys in updatedFormEl) {
           updatedFormEl[keys].value = '';
         }
        console.log(this.state.orderForm);


        this.setState({ loading: false, orderForm: updatedOrderForm });
        console.log(this.state.orderForm);
      })
```

and even in the first one the value sets to nothing!
why?

Comment: Are you mutating the actual state in some way?

Comment: *so festival I make a copy of state that have the form data*....festival?

Comment: Probably the form is resetting all the input fields, once you submit and before the axios call is resolved. You can try cloning before calling axios call.

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul
No , I get a copy and working with the copy so I believe the state didn't touch directly , But somehow It's touching and I don't know why!